# How to publish my WCF service to my website on remote server plesk panel

Tags: wcf, plesk

I prepared the wcf service application and it works on the localhost side, there is no problem here, but I cannot connect from my computer when I publish it at my address on the remote server via ftp method. 
I transfer my wcf service to my destination address via FTP method and the index.html page works where I transfer, but when I write the .svc file it gives 404 not found error. 
The company hosting the website where I will publish my wcf service provides shared hosting. 
I couldn't find anything in the settings section on my plesk panel. 
IIS settings of the remote server where my website is located cannot be changed. 
I wonder if I need to make a setting in the config file of the wcf service, such as the address or endpoint, or I do not know. 
I need your help on how I can run my wcf service that runs smoothly on my own computer but not working on my remote server website.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know the plesk. But if we host the WCF service in windows IIS web server, we need to enable certain Windows feature to process SVC extension.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.